# Can't set headers after they are sent when updating in node.js/mongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I'm a MEAN stack newbie and am attempting to perform multiple updates in a loop using the MongoDB driver for node.js.

When attempting to iterate through the records below via this call, I receive 'Can't set headers after they are sent', presumably because 'next' is called and called again on each subsequen iteration of the loop.

```
data.sortManual(manualSlug, proposedSortOrder, function(err) {
    if (err) {
        res.send(400, "Failed to update sort order");
    } else {
        res.send(200);
    }
});
```

If anybody can help me understand what I'm doing wrong, I'd really appreciate it.

`sortManual` method below:

```
manualData.sortManual = function(manualSlug, proposedSortOrder, next) {
    database.getDb(function(err, db) {
        if (!err) {
            var arrSortOrder = proposedSortOrder.split(',');

            for (var i = 0; i < arrSortOrder.length; i++) {

                arrSortOrder[i] = arrSortOrder[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, ""); // trim whitespace

                db.manuals.findAndModify({
                    slug: manualSlug,
                    "topics": {
                        "$elemMatch": {
                            "slug": arrSortOrder[i]
                        }
                    }
                }, [
                    ['_id', 'asc']
                ], {
                    $set: {
                        "topics.$.sort": i
                    }
                }, {
                    new: false,
                    upsert: true
                }, function(err, result) { <-- I probably shouldn't be doing this on each iteration of the loop but where to handle this?
                    if (err) {
                        console.log(err);
                        next(err, null);
                    } else {
                        console.log(result);
                        next(null, result);
                    }
                });
            } // end loop              
        } // end if
    }); // end getDb
}; // end sortManual
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has nothing to do with MongoDB, but the HTTP protocol.

The error message tells you that HTTP headers were set more than once, which is impossible based on Protocol definitions. *(Notice: we are talking about response, doesn't matter what inside of Mongo is happening)*.

The problem lies in callback `next` (the one which sends headers) is executed multiple times.

If you look into your code, you'll notice there is a `for` loop, and the `next` is used as callback in each of the loop steps - thus we have the problem.

#### Solution

You have to refactor the code to execute `next` only once, that can be done by [basic counting example](http://howtonode.org/control-flow):

```
        var counter = arrsortOrder.length;
        var errors = [];
        function checkIfLast(err) {
           if(err)   {
              errors.push(err);
           }
           counter--;
           if(counter == 0)  {
             if(errors.length > 0)
                next(errors.join());
             else
                next();
           }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < arrSortOrder.length; i++) {

            arrSortOrder[i] = arrSortOrder[i].replace(/^\s*/, "").replace(/\s*$/, ""); // trim whitespace

            db.manuals.findAndModify({
                slug: manualSlug,
                "topics": {
                    "$elemMatch": {
                        "slug": arrSortOrder[i]
                    }
                }
            }, [
                ['_id', 'asc']
            ], {
                $set: {
                    "topics.$.sort": i
                }
            }, {
                new: false,
                upsert: true
            }, function(err, result) { <-- I probably shouldn't be doing this on each iteration of the loop but where to handle this?
                if (err) {
                    checkIfLast(err);
                    console.log(err);
                    next(err, null);
                } else {
                    checkIfLast();
                    console.log(result);
                    next(null, result);
                }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have updated this to send a 200 response and am getting the same result.  Are you able to give me some clarity on the function after my findAndModify?

Comment: Oh I see what is your problem. You are calling your callback multiple times (it is inside of a `for` loop). Modify your code to execute the `callback` only once.

Comment: Got you - thanks.  I think I was getting confused about the use of next() as control flow in node.js.  Big help.  Thanks.

Comment: @Nick I modified the answer with respect to multiple callback calls issue.